# Has Isaiah 19:21 already been fulfilled?

Tags: isaiah, prophecy, egypt

Isaiah 19:21-22 NASB

> “Thus the Lord will make Himself known to Egypt, and the Egyptians will know the Lord in that day. They will even worship with sacrifice and offering, and will make a vow to the Lord and perform it. The Lord will strike Egypt, striking but healing; so they will return to the Lord, and He will respond to them and will heal them.”
> ‭‭

Has the prophecy about Egypt worshiping God and making vows to Him been fulfilled? If so, when?  How much of this chapter regarding Egypt has been fulfilled?

Answer (score 1):

As outline in the appendix below, most of the predictions of Isa 19 are probably still future, especially the second half of the chapter.  There is a striking parallel between the following three verses:

- Isa 19:1 - Behold, **the LORD rides on a swift cloud**; He is coming to Egypt. The idols of Egypt will tremble before Him ...
- Dan 7:13 - In my vision in the night I continued to watch, and I saw One like the **Son of Man coming with the clouds** of heaven. ...
- Rev 14:14 - And I looked and saw a white cloud, and **seated on the cloud was One like the Son of Man** ...

Whether this suggests that Isa 19 will be fulfilled at or just before Jesus second coming is not clear but the parallels cannot be ignored.

**APPENDIX - Predictions of Isa 19**

Isa 19 contains a series of predictions; but here we will concentrate on the latter half, from V16 onwards.

- V2 appears to describe a civil war; there were several of these in Egypt's history
- V3 describes the rise of spiritualism; this has essentially be true over thousands of years until the rise of Islam
- V4 says that harsh kings will rule over them - there have been plenty of these
- V5 - The water of the Nile dry up - such occurred on several occasions and may have been a cause of Joseph's famine (but this cannot be confirmed)

... and so forth.  However, when we get to V16, a series judgments of more spiritual/divine flavor occurs involving:

- V16, 17 - the land of Judah will bring terror on Egypt, Egypt will tremble over what the LORD of Hosts has planned
- V18 - five cities in the land of Egypt will speak the language of Canaan and swear allegiance to the LORD of Hosts
- V19-21 describes a series of events that is still, today, future, and that the LORD will send a savior to rescue them.
- V22 - Egypt struck by a plague that turns them to the LORD.

... and so forth.  All these are still future.  Further, the opening verse 1 suggests some kind of possible connection to Rev 14:14.